# Position Navbar between header and content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get my Navbar to appear in between my content and my header. When I change the values on my CSS it either appears right at the top of the screen, behind my header/content or in front of header/content (if i change the z-index) I would like it to appear in between both divs but if i add padding for example it will affect the positioning of the content below, it doesn't seem to do this at all at the moment.

Cheers

header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php       
 bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

    <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>


 </head>
 <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- header -->
        <header class="header clear" role="banner">

                <!-- logo -->
                <div class="headercenter">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-  
web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?  
>/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img"></a>

  <!-- /logo -->
                        </div>  


                <div class="information">
                <p class="t_header">Call Us</p>
                <p class="b_text">01209 215671</p>

                <p class="t_header">E-Mail Us</p>

                <p class="b_text">secretary@pennoweth.cornwall.sch.uk</p>


   <!-- /information -->
</div>

                    <!-- /headercenter -->



                </div>

                <!-- nav -->

                <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                    <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                </nav>

                <!-- /nav -->

        </header>
        <!-- /header -->
```

CSS

```
#nav{
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:relative;

left:0;
background:#555555;


}
```

Comment: If the navbar is supposed to be outside of the header...take it out of the header. We don't know enough about the rest of your CSS to comment otherwise. Perhaps a JSfiddle Demo?

Comment: The Nav needs to be in the header as i would like it to appear on every page, just after the header content (logo and contact info).
I can make a JSfiddle demo later, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info provided (could really use more detail and ideally a link) it sounds like you may have an ABSOLUTE position assigned to an element.  An absolutely positioned element will display relative to the first parent with RELATIVE position.

If you remove the "position: absolute" it should display within the flow of the 's.

Just an educated guess as to how two elements can occupy the same place!